# Why should my question be closed?

Tags: support, close-reasons, moderators, community

Why my question was closed? I have found same question on Magento Stack exchange. If My Question Closed Then Also this Question Should be closed.

This is Very Biased Things in this community.

**Other person Question Link:-**

[Certified Professional Developer Exam reading material](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216015/certified-professional-developer-exam-reading-material)

**My Question Link:-**

[Magento 2 : Javascript Developer Certification reading material](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/236339/magento-2-javascript-developer-certification-reading-material)

Please Review For Both links and give me justice.

Comment: cast reopen vote, I always supprt question that helps to community

Comment: I also see much time like it. If you have high reputation then people will not close your question.

There is lots of question which is opinion based but not closed because of that question was asked by a good reputation person. 

Also, the same people were an upvote if this question was asked by any high reputation person.

That is not fare.

Comment: yes, I had faced that while new in the community, many moderators and high reputed members closing or deleting questions or answer without reviewing or the big reason. This is not professionality even it demotivate new members. We are here to help others, not for demotivation.

Comment: cast my reopen vote. I think this question is clear and needed to be answered .

Comment: @QaisarSatti ...Thanks for your kind support.

Comment: @kunj everything have a process follow that like #Divyesh did. Blaming all high reputed members is not good.

Comment: @QaisarSatti, yes bro all are not like that but max people are doing same not reviewing question or answer. Actually, I do not want to disclose those members name, do not take it personally. Big power comes with big responsibility. Thanks for helping him.

Comment: @kunj for that you have option for moderator. contact them they will take care of that.